# Populate Woocommerce order notes with custom field value

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to populate a checkout form in Wordpress with the information from a custom checkout field, so that the information will be saved with the order and sent in the email.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'gfm_checkout_field_process');

function gfm_checkout_field_process( $fields ) {

    // Validate pickup date if user chose to pickup the order

    if (WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0] == 'local_pickup') {
        $pickup_date = strtotime($_POST["gfm_pickup_date"]);

        $fields['order']['order_comments'] = $pickup_date;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'webendev_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
/**
 * Change Order Notes Placeholder Text - WooCommerce
 * 
 */
function webendev_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Your custom placeholder';
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.